# How to align the nested scrolling elements with collapsing toolbar layout element?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

My designed layout has:

`LinearLayout` as a root element, following `coordinate layout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `NestedScrollView`

I am trying to attach the FirstName `EditText` with half portion of the background image (Second Image)(targeted design)
 but stuck here in this image(first Image) with following XML.
Any Suggestions, please.

[[image: My design]],

[[image: Requiements]]

```
ie.<Linear Layout>
        <Coordinate Layout>
            <AppBar>
            <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                <ImageView> (BackgroundImage)
                <TextView> (TitleName)
                <ButtonView> (back arrow) 
                <Toolbar>
            </CollapsingToolbarLayout>      
            </AppBarLayout> 


          <NestedScrollView>
              
             <!this view contains scolling elements i.e signup form >
             Note::This design has Linear Layout as root in vertical orientation.
             
           </NestedScrollView>  
           
        <Coordinate Layout>   
           
   </Linear Layout>
```

// Sample code snippet of my design

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SignUpActivity">



    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:translationZ="0.1dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        
        
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
        

            
            <!--Background Image (image of moutain)-->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name_app"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_background" />
            
            
            <!--Title Page (SignUp) i.e TextView -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title_name"
                style="@style/activity_font_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/sign_up" />
            
            
            <!-- Back button arrow-->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
                android:background="@null"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_arrow"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical" />
            
            
            
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        
        
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <include layout="@layout/signup_form" />
            
        
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        
        
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? What do you mean by alignment .. could you elaborate more

Comment: @Zain Elaborate::Trying to set nested scrollview layout items
stick with half of the background image and start to scroll from there.
like with the use of xml property margintop or margin bottom.